# [__NSCFBoolean count]: unrecognized selector : Best way to prevent this crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I am getting this error on the conditional if statement. Is there a good way to prevent this error from showing up? Any tips or suggestions are appreciated. I am guessing subanswer for some reason is a boolean.

```
id subAnswer = [answer objectForKey:@"answer"];
NSArray *subAnswerKeyList;
if (subAnswer != [NSNull null] && subAnswer != nil && [subAnswer count] > 0 ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `if` statement with:

```
if ([subAnswer isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [subAnswer count]) {
}
```

Your `subAnswer` is actually a number representing a `BOOL` value. You need to see why you expect it to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

your "`subAnswer`" object is almost certainly not the NSArray object you're expecting it to be.

Put a "`NSLog("subAnswer is %@", subAnswer);`" in your code there and your Xcode console will tell you what the object *really* is.